# Pass a javascript onclick function selected items in next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a 3 step restaurant menu  items order form , that form already coded code in html with JavaScript,  but i think  some thing is wrong in the function in query or JavaScript, and it not working properly,  main the order calculation

3 . Step form details:

1. menu.html :

   here user will add the menu items by click a button (image), then clicked items will show in same page right side then click checkout button.
2. payment.html :

   here i want  to just show that selected items that i already select for order, then  user will review that and click checkout button
3. delivery.html :

   here they will see there total order price a button.. on this step they  need to also put there name address, city, etc...  like a form registration & a bottom a button place order now, after click that site owner get a message .

****** html code  menu.html ******

```
<li>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <p>Grilled Fish Fillet</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p>150 SR</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button onclick="addtoCard('grilledfishfillet','Grilled Fish Fillet', 150)" style="border:none; background:none;"><img src="images/plus.jpg" alt=""></button>

        </div>
</li>
```

****** delivery.html******

```
<div id="OrderItem">
    <input name="order1" placeholder="" type="text" id="order1" size="30" value=""  class="form-control  input-lg"><br>
    <input name="order2"  placeholder=" " type="text" id="order2" size="30" value=""  class="form-control  input-lg"><br>
    <input name="order3" placeholder=" " type="text" id="order3" size="30" value=""  class="form-control  input-lg"><br>
    <input name="order4" placeholder="" type="text" id="order4" size="30" value=""  class="form-control  input-lg"><br>
</div>
```

***** payment.html page****

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value=""  class="form-control  input-lg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input name="lname" type="text" id="lname" size="30" value=""  class="form-control input-lg">
    </div>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:40px;padding:5px 30px;" class="bg-color">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h3 style="padding-top:10px; text-align:center; font-size:24px;">Total : 246.00 SAR</h3>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use session or cookies

Comment: Use Session Variable To Pass Data from one page to another page

Comment: You can use `localStorage` to pass data from one page to another.

Comment: `localStorage` will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to pass data from one page to another. The basic syntax is:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

Setting a value:

```
localStorage.setItem('myObj', 'My Object');
```

And getting a value:

```
localStorage.getItem('myObj');
```

If `localStorage` is not supported, you can always fall back to one of the cookies or URL rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

Passing Value From One Page To Another Page using `localStorage`

```
var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage HTML's `localStorage` and/or `sessionStorage` to pass the values around. These are HTML features set but needs JavaScript to manipulate.

A `localStorage` will store any value you assign persistently whereas `sessionStorage` will hold for a session only - just like cookie vs session in PHP. Syntactically both are same.

You can use syntax like this to store values -

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

where key is your identifier and value is the data you want to store. In order to retrieve the value, you can call this -

```
localStorage.getItem(key);
```

So, you can store your value from one page using setItem and retrieve on other using getItem.

Couple of points to note here:

- Think about the data persistence.
- Since localStorage forever saves the data (unless deleted manually/
  browser cleanup), you must think when it should be needed and when
  sessionStorage is enough.
- localStorage is ultimately universal JavaScript object.
- Instead of getter and setter method, you can access/ modify
  properties directly if you want. e.g. localStorage.key = value;
  (setter), var x = localStorage.key; (getter).